# Flutter - Camera not initialized (LateInitializationError) when passing over in Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple app with bottom navigation bar. I tested and it works if i have a button that pass from the same 'home.dart' page to 'scanner_page.dart' (camera page). However, I faced 'LateInitializationError' for camera when I have that in bottom navigation bar.

How can I get the scenario 2 working with bottom navigation bar or adding `await async` to returning the building of the material page route widget?

Scenario 1 (working) -
[image]

- Under my bottom navigation bar's navigator, I have set 3 pages, Home (default), Scan (camera), Account (setting).
- There is a separated elevated button which i tried in the same `home.dart` that route to the same `scanner_page.dart`, opening up the camera
- The `home.dart` only get the camera list, passing to scanner page, the scanner page will initialize the camera

[image]
[image]

Scenario 2 (not working, LateInitializationError) -

- I initialize it in the `home.dart` class itself,

  late List cameras;

  ```
  Future<void> camera() async {
    // Obtain a list of the available cameras on the device.
    cameras = await availableCameras();
  }
  ```

and just return the page

[image]

[image]

but it is not initialized

[image]

My full code in `home.dart`:

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'scanner_page.dart';
import 'nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' hide EmailAuthProvider;
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const HomeScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
  });

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  // int currentPageIndex = 0;
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  late List<CameraDescription> cameras;

  final providers = [EmailAuthProvider()];

  Future<void> camera() async {
    // Obtain a list of the available cameras on the device.
    cameras = await availableCameras();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: NavBar(navigatorKey: navigatorKey),
      body: Navigator(key: navigatorKey, onGenerateRoute: generateRoute),
    );
  }

  Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case "Account":
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return ProfileScreen(
              providers: providers,
              actions: [
                SignedOutAction((context) {
                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/sign-in');
                }),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      case "Scan":
        // return FutureBuilder<Widget>(
        //   future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        //   builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
        //     if (snapshot.hasData) {
        //       return MaterialPageRoute(
        //         builder: (context) async => ScannerPage(cameras: cameras),
        //       );
        //     } else {
        //       return CircularProgressIndicator();
        //     }
        //   },
        // );
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ScannerPage(cameras: cameras),
        );
      default: // default to home page
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: const Text('Open camera'),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await availableCameras().then(
                        (cameras) => Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    ScannerPage(cameras: cameras))),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
  }
}
```

My `scanner_page.dart` will initialize the camera:

```
class ScannerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<CameraDescription> cameras;

  const ScannerPage({
    super.key,
    required this.cameras,
  });

  @override
  ScannerPageState createState() => ScannerPageState();
}

class ScannerPageState extends State<ScannerPage> {
  // Add code to initialize camera and capture images
  late CameraController cameraController;
  late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;

  Future<void> setupCameras(CameraDescription cameras) async {
    // Create a camera controller
    cameraController = CameraController(cameras, ResolutionPreset.medium);

    // Initialize the controller, this returns a Future.
    try {
      _initializeControllerFuture = cameraController.initialize();
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {});
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      debugPrint("camera error $e");
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // call the function above to initialize the camera
    setupCameras(widget.cameras[0]);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose of the controller when the widget is disposed.
    cameraController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
......... rest of the code ...
  // Add code to send captured image to the backend
```